# Error on adding the Menu items

Tags: android

I am using `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in my activity and trying to add the menu items using `menu.add()`.

Eg: `menu.add(0,INFO,0,"Info")`. Suppose i have this line in my code, i am getting error on INFO. What should be done to solve this?

Comment: Depends, what's the error say?

Comment: INFO is the Item ID. Under the switch statement, if i use case INFO: i get the error saying that INFO cannot be resolved.

Comment: It's probably easier for you to just post the whole `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method for us to look at

Answer (score 0):

I post an example for you how I'm doing it. So you have something to compare.
Please **tell us if you found your Problem**, this question could help others then too :) 
If you give some of your code we can investigate your problem :)

**In the activity:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.abort_menu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

**XML in menu folder (abort_menu.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
  <item
    android:id="@+id/abort_menu"
    android:title="@string/abort"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:menuCategory="alternative"
    android:titleCondensed="@string/abort"
    android:visible="true"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="@string/abort"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
 />

</menu>
```